# eval single python command from bash

Tags: python, bash

I'm too lazy for:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Feb 27 2021, 15:10:58) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> hex(3*0xface+122)
'0x2f0e4'
>>> quit()
```

So I started using

```
$ echo "print(hex(3*0xface+122))" | python
0x2f0e4
```

When I remove the wrapping `print(...)` command nothing happens.

- Why is that?
- The interpreted version works without the `print(...)`

Comment: In the top, you are using a REPL, which is a **R**ead, **Evaluate**, **P**rint **L**oop. It automatically prints the value of the expression. Outside of a REPL, it won't print something you don't tell it to print. Note, *both* are interpreted. The CPython runtime uses an interpreter always

Comment: As an aside, you can use `python -c "print(hex(3*0xface+122))"`

Comment: If you generally like to use python and want to be able to execute python code directly, you can also use a python powered shell. For example IPython or Xonsh